# ClickOnce: Shortcut to content file

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, clickonce

I have written and deployed a ClickOnce app that has some content files located in a directory at the same level as the exe.  I can find these files under

C:\Users\vhacpabeaudb\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\DZ8LE60V.JXC\H0472BOZ.KGP\vapa..tion_2c7673512b48a223_0002.0002_4712fd016c82a834\Macros

So, I can easily drag one of these files on to my desktop and create a shortcut.  However, I can't share that shortcut file with another user since the content file it references is in a completely different path.

Is there any way to reference files like this in a consistent way between click once installations?  Or is there a more appropriate place to store common files?

Comment: Sometimes I feel like my questions are so obvious and that's why no one takes the time to reply.  Is this one of those cases?

Comment: Why cant you copy these content files to any other drives rather than C. and Keep the integrity??

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I came up with no valid answer or way to achieve what I'm trying to do.  You have to play within the Click-Once boundaries.